# How to zip only .txt file in a folder using java?

Tags: java, file-io, zip

here i'm trying to zip only .txt file in a folder using java.

My code here was found with google and works perfectly but only for a specified .txt file.

Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;
import java.io.*;


public class ZipFile
  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ZipOutputStream out = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        File inputFile1 = new File("c:\\Target\\target.txt");// here i want to say only the directroy where .txt files are stored
        File outputFile = new File("c:\\Target\\Archive_target.zip");//here i want to put zipped file in a different directory

        OutputStream rawOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
        out = new ZipOutputStream(rawOut);

        InputStream rawIn = new FileInputStream(inputFile1);
        in = new BufferedInputStream(rawIn);


        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("c:\\Target\\target.txt");
        out.putNextEntry(entry);
        byte[] buf = new byte[2048];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
            if(out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ignored)
                { }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use File.list(...) to get a list of all the text files in the folder. Then you create a loop to write each file to the zip file.

Answer (score 1):

I just add these lines just after 
"File outputFile = new File("c:\Target\Archive_target.zip"); 
from my previous code.

code added:

```
File Dir = new File("c:/Target");
            FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
      public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        return !name.startsWith(".txt");
      }
    };
    String[] children = Dir.list(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all text files in your directory by using the following method of the File class:
     String[]   list(FilenameFilter filter)
Create a File object that points to your DIRECTORY (I know it sounds illogical, but that's the way it is- you can test if it is a directory using isDirectory()) and then use the FilenameFilter to say, for example, accept this file if its name contain ".txt"

Comment: Ok when i try your tip, i have a message like :

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\Target (Access refused)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at ZipFile.main(ZipFile.java:37)

Comment: @user618111: please show what you have done, and the error message, in an edit to the question. This way it is easier to help you. (It looks like the directory is not readable, or you are trying to read a directory as a file).

Answer (score 0):

Create a FilenameFilter that accepts only *.txt file , and then just use

list = File.list(yourNameFilter);

and then just add all the files in the list to the zip file